# More than one left identity and uniqueness

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reading Discrete Mathematics by Lipschutz, topic Algebraic Systems. It says identity element is unique and goes on to give the proof as $e f = e $ and $ef = f$ so $e = f$. It's fine until then but in the next line it says:

> This theorem tells us, in particular, that an identity element is
> unique, and that if an operation has more than one left identity then
> it has no right identity, and vice versa.

The problem is it mentions in the same line the uniqueness of identity as well as the possibility of having multiple distinct left identities as a corollary. Mathematically it can be proved as [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/More_than_one_Left_Identity_then_no_Right_Identity), but the problem is how can  both of these be true at the same time?

Comment: An "identity" is an element that is both a left and right identity. If there is such an element, then it is unique, and there are no other left or right identities. If there isn't such an element, there can still be left identities (and no right identities) or right identities (and no left identities). There is no contradiction.

Comment: @runway44 thanks it cleared up my doubt.